# How can I include newlines when using appendTo(), insertAfter(), etc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I want to add several DIVs to a container, like in this **over-simplified** example:

```
for(var x=0; x<3; x++) {
  $("<div>"+x+"</div>").appendTo("#parent");
}
```

The result (when viewing source) would be something like this:

```
<div id="parent"><div>0</div><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>
```

Similarly, the result of $("#parent").html() would be this:

```
<div>0</div><div>1</div><div>2</div>
```

But what if I want the source to look like this: *(nevermind proper indentation)*

```
<div id="parent">
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
</div>
```

So that the result of $("#parent").html() would instead be this:

```
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
```

I thought *this* would work, but the newline was ignored and wouldn't have accounted for the first linebreak after [div id="parent"] anyway.

```
for(var x=0; x<3; x++) {
  $("<div>"+x+"</div>\n").appendTo("#parent");
}
```

Any suggestions?

One of the reasons for the newline formatting is because the resulting HTML will need to be parsed line by line and converted to XML for storage. To complicate matters, there will be nested DIVs, like this:

```
<div>
  <div>0</div>
  <div>1</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

Without linebreaks, the above would have to be parsed as this:

```
<div><div>0</div><div>1</div></div><div><div>2</div></div>
```

If parsing the single line of HTML above is easier than inserting a bunch of newlines, then I'm all ears for the how-to and would actually prefer that!

Comment: Why? It makes no difference... The generated HTML is was it is, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: An XML parser will have no problem with the lack of newlines, so your requirement makes no sense. But you shouldn't be trying to parse HTML with an XML parser anyway.

Comment: @elclanrs new lines can make a difference depending on the browser and the styling. For example: `<span>A</span><span>B</span>` is not rendered the same as `<span>A</span>\n<span>B</span>` (there's a white space between the A and the B).

Comment: "If parsing the single line of HTML above is easier than inserting a bunch of newlines, then I'm all ears for the how-to and would actually prefer that!"

Whoa. Whoa. Whoa. Are you writing your own HTML parser? If so. STOP. :) If not, *any* worthwhile HTML parser won't CARE about newlines.

Comment: Thanks all. I already suspect that what I'm trying to do is a terrible (or at least misguided) idea. I'm mainly just curious about how to include newlines using these jQuery methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/155/

(check the console)

```
<div id="parent">
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = '';
    for(var x=0; x<3; x++) {
      html += "<div>" + x + "</div>\n";
    }
    $('#parent').append(html);
    console.log($("#parent").html());
});
```

Comment: Ugh! of course. I've done it this way before to reduce append() calls and totally forgot. Thanks for including the jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

Using `appendTo` does not work, but changing the order and using `append` actually does work:

Try this:

```
$("#parent").append("<div>"+x+"</div>\n");
```

Instead of this:

```
$("<div>"+x+"</div>").appendTo("#parent");
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why the difference. Unfortunately, there's no similar alternative when using insertAfter(), etc. (Or is there?)

Comment: You could use `after()` (instead of `insertAfter()`) in the same way

Answer (score 0):

If you are really bothered by it ...generate full strings instead which actually results in less function calls and less appends to the DOM which are expensive

```
var htm = '';
for(var x=0; x<3; x++) {
  htm+= "<div>" + x + "</div>\n";
}
$("#parent").append(htm);// only one append
```

You could even add `\t` for tabbing.

Comment: Awesome. This totally solves it, but I had to accept indupitablee's equivalent answer for being posted a few seconds sooner and for including the jsfiddle. Thank you!